# How to display the user's image in a Message Template?

Tags: 8, tokens, message-subscribe

I activated the sub-module "Message Example" of the module "Message".

I added the token in the "Example - User register" message template :

```
[message:author:user_picture:thumbnail]
```

When a message is created, it displays the url of the user's image.

How to display the user's image in a Message Template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following token: `[message:author:user_picture]` i.e. same as yours with the thumbnail subsection

UPDATE:
In order to get the image styles to work I had to switch to "Full HTML" text filter, then while editing the "Source" I added this line:

`<img src="[message:author:user_picture:thumbnail]" />`

And it worked for me like this.

Comment: I just tested and there is nothing posted, not even the link

Comment: Strange because this works in my installation

Comment: It works. The problem is that when there is a default image, it is not displayed. Now how to display with the image style thumbnail ? Because the images are displayed in 100x100 with the original dimension (they are heavy).

Comment: @m1lbt I updates my answer, please check it